# asp.net mvc : create listbox using formcollection

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, listbox, selectlist, formcollection

I'm experiencing current error in my view:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master"  Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<ProjectenII.Models.Domain.StudentModel>"%>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    IndexStudents
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2>IndexStudents</h2>

  <%using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <%=Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.NormalSelected, new MultiSelectList(Model.NormalStudentsList, "StudentNummer", "Naam", Model.NormalSelected), new { size = "6" }); %>

    <input type="submit" name="add" 
                          id="add" value=">>" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="remove" 
                          id="remove" value="<<" />
    <%=Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.NoClassSelected, new MultiSelectList(Model.StudentsNoClassList, "StudentNummer", "Naam", Model.NoClassSelected)); %>
  <% } %>

  <%=Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Save) %>
  <input type="submit" name="apply" id="apply" value="Save!" />
</asp:Content>
```

It gives me an error at the listboxfor() method... saying ") expected".

But I close all the opening tags... very strange though!
What I want to use it for: I want to move items from one listbox to the other and then update the database. So I'd like to do it using formCollection, unless there is another way?

Students have a field named "classID", when I update the database, that value needs to change from the current value to "0". I think the best way is using formCollections? Isn't it? 
This is my StudentModel

```
   public class StudentModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Student> NormalStudentsList { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Student> StudentsNoClassList { get; set; }
        public string[] NormalSelected { get; set; }
        public string[] NoClassSelected { get; set; }
        public string Save { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult IndexStudents(Docent docent, int id, int klasgroepid)
        {
            var studentModel = new StudentModel
            {
               NormalStudentsList = docent.GeefStudenten(id, klasgroepid),
               StudentsNoClassList = docent.GeefStudenten(id, klasgroepid)
            };

            return View(studentModel);
        }
```

I have two questions: how can I fix the error? AND how can I update the database?

I suggest using "UpdateModel()" ... ?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your second question is because you didn't include the code you're using to persist your model to the database.

The ")" expected error is because you have a semicolon at the end of your ListBoxFor method call.

It should look like this:

```
<%=Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.NormalSelected, new MultiSelectList(Model.NormalStudentsList, "StudentNummer", "Naam", Model.NormalSelected), new { size = "6" }) %>
```

When you use <%= you don't need the semicolon.